# Time differene query on mysql using LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have a table (LocationEntries) that contians the time (timeReceived) my application received the location  of some devices. The mentioned devices have a unique subscriberId. 
A second table contians these subscriberIds and the actual Id of each device.

I would like to identify devices that send location updates less than 10 seconds apart. 
A query similar to the one below:

```
SELECT LocationEntries.subscriberId, LocationEntries.timeReceived, Subscriber.id,
    Subscriber.suid 
FROM LocationEntries 
LEFT JOIN LocationEntries ON (LocationEntries.timeReceived - LocationEntries.timeReceived =< 10 ) 
LEFT JOIN Subscriber ON (Subscriber.id = subscriberId) 
GROUP BY Subscriber.id
```

However I am not sure if it is possible to do a LEFT JOIN of a table on itself since I get *Not unique table/akias: 'LocationEntries'* error everytime I try to execute the command. 
What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

I managed to find a valid query.

```
SELECT suid 
FROM Subscribers s 
LEFT JOIN LocationEntries l1 ON (s.id = l1.subscriberId) 
LEFT JOIN LocationEntries l2 ON (s.id = l2.subscriberId)
WHERE l1.timeReceived < l2.timeReceived AND TIMEDIFF(l2.timeReceived, l1.timeReceived) <= '00:00:10.0'
GROUP BY s.id
```

However, because the number of enteries in the table (close to 4,000,000) is too many the query does not provide a result any a timely fashion.

Comment: Can you include the output of `show create table LocationEntries`? If you can, please also include some sample data

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do a join between the same table, just need to put aliases... 
However, I don't quite sure if that is what you need...

Maybe this can work:

```
select LE.subscriberId, LE.timeReceived, SU.id, SU.suid
FROM LocationEntries LE 
LEFT JOIN Subscriber SU 
  ON SU.id = LE.subscriberId
WHERE LE.timeReceived =< 10
group by Subscriber.id;
```

The idea of made a Join of the same table is for example that you have a record with a value in one column and you want to get another record/row that have the same value but in another column

Comment: You're right about the alises, but the bigger problem is that he is trying to `SELECT` non aggregate columns in a `GROUP BY` query.

Comment: The LE.timeReceived =< 10 seem to have some syntax error corresponding to it. Are you sure that the =< 10 operator will be appropriate for this?